# How to select a node using XPath if sibling node has a specific value?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following document:

```
<a>
  <bb>abc</bb>
  <cc>ccc</cc>
  <dd>ddd</dd>
</a>
<a>
  <bb>zz</bb>
  <cc>1</cc>
  <dd>2</dd>
</a>
```

How can I get the value of `<cc>` using XPath  if `<bb>` is `zz`?

Comment: the problem is i know how to access a specific node, but i have no idea of accessing a node if a sibling having specific value. Can it be something like this /a/cc/contains(/a/bb='zz') ?

Answer (score 126):

<strike>Not sure why everybody is querying for siblings,</strike> you can also check for `<bb/>`-elements matching the predicate from `<a/>`'s predicate:

```
//a[bb/text() = "zz"]/cc/text()
```

Comment: *"Not sure why everybody is querying for siblings"*: Perhaps because the question was for sibling.. ;-)

Comment: Seems I actually didn't read the title. :) Answer stays valid anyway.

Comment: Your answer queries for siblings too. You just didn't use a `*-sibling` axis. +1 though.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but it answers my actual question that I formulated badly. Thank you!

Answer (score 49):

What you need is `following-sibling` XPath axis

```
//a/bb[text()="zz"]/following-sibling::cc[1]/text()
```

Test the Xpath here: http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/b55ec3ac-dfa4-4f44-81e8-f963ea4a0625

Comment: @HOESENGKIANG: you should click the check mark to "accept" this answer, or whichever one you think answers the question best.

Answer (score 31):

Q: *How to select a node using XPath if sibling node has a specific value?*
Because there are only "XPath Axes" for following-siblings and preceding-siblings, you can use one of them if the position is fixed.

**But better:**
Look for `cc` were the parent has child `bb` with value `'zz'`:

```
//cc[../bb='zz']
```

Comment: Either that or `//a[bb = 'zz']/cc`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'only "XPath Axes" for following-sibling and preceding-sibling'. Are you referring to the fact that there is no single axis for all siblings?

Comment: @LarsH :Yes sorry, (excuse my bad English :-( ) - that was what I was trying to say. (Because the question was for siblings.)

Answer (score 10):

First off, your example is not well-formed XML. Overlooking that and that you didn't describe your intents very well (What exactly do you want to select on which condition?), I assume you want to do this:

```
//cc[preceding-sibling::bb[text()="zz"]]/text()
```

It selects

```
TEXT VALUES OF ALL <CC> ELEMENTS
//cc                                    /text()
    THAT HAVE A PRECEDING SIBLING <BB>
    [preceding-sibling::bb             ]
                          THAT HAS TEXT VALUE EQUAL TO "zz"
                          [text()="zz"]
```

You could write is also as

```
//bb[text()="zz"]/following-sibling::cc/text()
```

Please look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), it has some very well readable [examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) from which you'll learn a lot.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks for the correction from "not valid" to "not well-formed". I learnt something new today.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution for this problem is

`//bb[contains(.,'zz')]/../cc/text()`

**Explanation**: Any `bb` that contains `'zz'` string in all the child nodes of `bb` then going to parent node of that `bb` using `..`, now that we can access the `cc` so returning text.

I hope that explanation isn't complex.

Answer (score 4):

```
//a/cc[../bb='zz']/text()
```

//a            : Selects all 'a' elements no matter where it is.

//a/cc         : Selects 'cc' elements that are children of the 'a' element (no matter where a is).

..             : Selects the parent of the current node.

[../bb='zz']   : where value of sibling 'bb' element is zz.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp