# Fetch content based on XML content validation in bash

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, xml-parsing

I have an XML as follows

```
<demos>
 <demo>
  <a>00</a>
  <b>First</b>
  <c>ProjectA</c>
 </demo>
 <demo>
  <a>01</a>
  <b>Second</b>
  <c>ProjectB</c>
 </demo>
</demos>
```

Example 1: If within `<a>` tag has `00` and `<c>` tag has `ProjectA`, **Output** should be `First`

Example 2: If within `<a>` tag has `01` and `<c>` tag has `ProjectB`, **Output** should be `Second`

I want try with xml_grep or xpath as these are installed packages in linux by default. I tried different ways such as

```
xpath xtest.xml '//a[text()="01"]/text() | //b'
```

but this validation doesnt work.

Comment: Both `If` conditions in your question are true for the sample XML. What should be the output?

Comment: I highlighted the output. its two different examples.

Comment: Are you asking about how to select a sibling? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040254/how-to-select-a-node-using-xpath-if-sibling-node-has-a-specific-value

Comment: You should probably drop the [linux], [bash] and [shell] tags, imho this is an xpath question.

Comment: Which kind of command **xpath** do you have? On my system, I would have to run: `xpath -e '//a[text()="01"]/text() | //b' xtest.xml` instead.

Comment: its probably a version of suse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example 1, you will have to run:

```
xpath -q -e '//demo[(a/text()="00") and (c/text()="ProjectA")]/b/text()' xtest.xml
```

For example 2:

```
xpath -q -e '//demo[(a/text()="01") and (c/text()="ProjectB")]/b/text()' xtest.xml
```

Be aware that xpath is not installed by default on any Linux. On Ubuntu, you will first have to run `sudo apt install libxml-xpath-perl`.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked with XML as file.xml

```
 xpath file.xml '//demo[a/text()="00" and c/text()="ProjectA"]/b/text()'
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu with **xpath** installed along with **libxml-xpath-perl**. Probably, you have another flavour of xpath.

Comment: This is suse linux

Answer (score 0):

Robust **`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//demo/a' --if '. = 00 and ./following-sibling::c="ProjectA"' \
-v './following-sibling::b' -n input.xml
```

The output:

```
First
```

---

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//demo/a' --if '. = 01 and ./following-sibling::c="ProjectB"' \
-v './following-sibling::b' -n input.xml
```

The output:

```
Second
```