# how to extract element in xml if the 'child' has given tag?

Tags: python, xml

```
<people>
 <type>
  <name>lo_123</name>
  <country>AUS</country>
  <note>
     <name>joe</name>
     <age>26</age>
     <spouse>
         <name>lisa</name>
         <gender>f</gender>
     </spouse>     
  </note>
 </type>
<type>
  <name>hi_123</name>
  <country>AUS</country>
  <note>
     <name>paul</name>
     <gender>m</gender>
     <age>28</age>
     <spouse>
         <name>mona</name>
         <gender>f</gender>
     </spouse>     
  </note>
 </type>
</people>
```

I need to extract `name` that has `gender` like 'Paul'. But I dont know how to filter the 'child' that has `gender`.

Here is my code that I knew:

```
xml='xmltest.xml'

crif_tree = ET.parse(xml)
crif_root = crif_tree.getroot()

for a in _root.findall('./type/note/name'):
    print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `crif_root.findall('./type/note[gender]/name')`: it selects a `note` only if it has a child `gender`. in case `gender` needs to have a particular value, see [How to select a node using XPath if sibling node has a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040254/how-to-select-a-node-using-xpath-if-sibling-node-has-a-specific-value)