# How to loop through two XML files and print result

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've been trying unsuccessfully with PHP to loop through two XML files and print the result to the screen. The aim is to take a country's name and output its regions/states/provinces as the case may be.

The first block of code successfully prints all the countries but the loop through both files gives me a blank screen.

The countries file is in the format:

```
<row>
    <id>6</id>
    <name>Andorra</name>
    <iso2>AD</iso2>
    <phone_code>376</phone_code>
  </row>
```

And the states.xml:

```
<row>
    <id>488</id>
    <name>Andorra la Vella</name>
    <country_id>6</country_id>
    <country_code>AD</country_code>
    <state_code>07</state_code>
  </row>
```

so that country_id = id.

This gives a perfect list of countries:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("countries.xml");
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("states.xml");

foreach($xml->children() as $key => $children) {
  print((string)$children->name); echo "<br>";
}
```

This gives me a blank screen except for the HTML stuff on the page:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("countries.xml");
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("states.xml");
$s = "Jamaica";
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
  foreach($xml1->children() as $child2){ 
    if ($child->id == $child2->country_id && $child->name == $s) {
        print((string)$child2->name);
        echo "<br>";
    }
   }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your first example has an extra `}`.

Comment: Thanks. A typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is not casting the name to a string before doing your comparison. But why are you starting the second loop before checking if it's needed? You're looping through every single item in `states.xml` needlessly.

```php
$countries = simplexml_load_file("countries.xml");
$states = simplexml_load_file("states.xml");
$search = "Jamaica";

foreach($countries->children() as $country) {
    if ((string)$country->name !== $search) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach($states->children() as $state) { 
        if ((string)$country->id === (string)$state->country_id) {
            echo (string)$state->name . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, note that naming your variables in a descriptive manner makes it much easier to figure out what's going on with code.

---

You could probably get rid of the loops altogether using an XPath query to [match the sibling value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040254/how-to-select-a-node-using-xpath-if-sibling-node-has-a-specific-value/17042268). I don't use SimpleXML, but here's what it would look like with DomDocument:

```php
$search = "Jamaica";

$countries = new DomDocument();
$countries->load("countries.xml");
$xpath = new DomXPath($countries);
$country = $xpath->query("//row[name/text() = '$search']/id/text()");
$country_id = $country[0]->nodeValue;

$states = new DomDocument();
$states->load("states.xml");
$xpath = new DomXPath($states);
$states = $xpath->query("//row[country_id/text() = '$country_id']/name/text()");
foreach ($states as $state) {
    echo $state->nodeValue . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. I agree with you that the looping might be resource intensive. There are more than 30-thousand lines of states (only 239 countries). I did try looping only the countries and "comparing" the states but still no luck. But I'm a media person, not a coder, just doing enough to skimp along. Your XPath worked perfectly. Thanks. I'll have to read up on that. The first option performed like my attempts. I don't think this has to do with the problem but I've been testing from the php server running in console so I'll put it in the web root and see...

Comment: Needed to add the typecast to string in the ID comparison as well. Should be working now, but XPath is much better anyway.

Comment: Agreed. Though I'm not yet familiar with it, it seems straightforward. I assume it gets the path through the nodes. And yes, with the typecasting the loop method also works. A twofer...